# OOP is secure but how?

Tags: oop

Well We have alot of things to say about Object oriented programing but oftenly I listen a sentence "`OOP is secure coding`"? I can understand that OOP is managable , reuseable and almost all other things but truley from the very first day I am unable to understand that How OOP is secure or What does writer/speaker mean by this.....
Thanks

Comment: I usually assume the writer/speaker does not know what they are talking about and move on.

Comment: Sounds like poppycock to me. Secure coding and programming paradigm choice are largely orthogonal.

Comment: OOP is not any more secure in the sense of "protecting against exploits" than other coding methods. It may or may not make it easier to implement secure systems due to its other benefits. But there's nothing inherently secure or insecure about any coding methodology.

Comment: OOP is no more secure than procedural code unless the developer takes the appropriate steps to make it secure.

Comment: well...I suppose the speaker/writer is Chinese cuz that's how they mean concealment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely not more secure than functional or procedural programming, nor less secure. As security lies in the hands of the programmer, I fail to see how OO is "more secure".